# AVPlayer vs MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios-4.2, avplayer

In my application I have to play videos of type .m3u8. **These are not local video**. I can do it either with MPMoviePlayerController or AVPlayer. I also have to ignore userinteraction when some advertisement is getting played. Also I have to give an option for Airplay.

Which player should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AVPlayer has a subclass called AVQueuePlayer which allows you to play back several movies in a sequence. It would be helpful for you for your ads. AVplayer currently does not support Airplay.

From iOS 5 AVplayer has an option to start playing back automatically on Airplay by enabling usesAirPlayVideoWhileAirPlayScreenIsActive property (if allowsAirPlayVideo is also enabled)
As far as I know you cannot play on airplay automatically with MPMoviePlayer, user has to tap on the Airplay icon.

Comment: I don't want to start airplay automatically. it will start when user will click some button. But I want to do it using AVPlayer + MPVolumeView. Is this possible?